# Webpack --watch does not work on Windows (nor webpack-dev-server)

Tags: windows-7, npm, webpack, watch, fsevents

It seems to be a common problem, but after a few days of active searching I didn't find any solution that works in my case.

- windows7-x64
- node: 6.3.0-x64 (also tried node-v4.4.7-x64)
- npm: 3.10.3
- webpack: 1.13.1
- sublime text (not Vim)

---

First of all, I can't install **fsevents** on windows, which might be the problem, because it's the library for watching on OS X.

```
D:\file>npm install webpack
file@1.0.0 D:\file
`-- webpack@1.13.1

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.13
```

So, if your `--watch` works on windows, please tell me, do you have the same issue with skipping fsevents when installing webpack?

---

Secondly, `webpack --watch` does compile the file, but it doesn't watch at all.

E.g. if I use stylus watch, then it actually blocks my command line until I press **ctrl+c**

```
D:\file>stylus -w style.styl  
watching C:/Users/...  
compiled style.css  
watching style.styl
_
```

And only after **ctrl+c** it will unblock my keyboard.

```
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

[stylus-watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFOXl.jpg)

While `webpack -w` is totally different. It's not just not compiling the file on changes, but it's also not watching at all. I mean that after typing the command `webpack --watch` it's compiling the file one time, but it doesn't lock my keyboard and so it allows me to write another command.

```
D:\webpa>webpack main.js bundle.js
D:\webpa>webpack -w main.js bundle.js
D:\webpa>webpack --watch main.js bundle.js
D:\webpa>
```

[webpack-watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbYHU.jpg)

The same with `webpack-dev-server` - it starts server, but then immediately finishes it.

```
D:\webpa>webpack-dev-server --hot --inline
http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from D:\webpa
D:\webpa>
```

---

It looks like the problem is not with webpack.config.js, because it doesn't watch even with a command like `webpack --watch main.js bundle.js`, but anyway, here is my basic config.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
};
```

And I've tried many other variants:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var entry = path.join(__dirname, "main.js");
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: entry,
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {root: [__dirname]},
  resolve: { fallback: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") },
  resolveLoader: { fallback: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin(),
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    ),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors/js/applibs.js'),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
  ]
};
```

As I said, the problem seems to be not in webpack.config.js

---

I've also tried things like:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
webpack-dev-server --content-base ./ --port 9966 --hot --inline
webpack --watch --watch-poll
rename/move/create new folder, reinstall node.js and webpack
```

So yeah, if you had this issue and you **resolved** it, please share some info.

- Did you have problems with installing **fsevents**?
- Was your `webpack --watch` command blocking your keyboard and actually watching, but just not compiling files after changes? Or was it finishing watching immediately like in my case?
- Any other suggestions what to use apart from `--watch` and `webpack-dev-server`?

Thanks!

Comment: fsevents might be like a unix specific thing.  I get the same warnings on Windows and it wasn't a problem so you can eliminate that.

Comment: I also had luck with adding `watchOptions: {
aggregateTimeout: 300,
poll: 1000
},` to my dev server config.  I had to actually make a dev server config rather than just relying on webpack-dev-server CLI though.  See https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver

Comment: @mjohnsonengr, thanks for your help! Yes, I forgot to mention, that I've also tried `watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },`, but it didn't work out. Can you may be share your webpack.config.js and dev server config? And by the way, does your `--watch` work properly from the beginning?

Comment: Had same problem (well, similar), of dev-server not always picking up on changes, and got it to always pick up changes by using the "watchOptions" fix above. Here's my complete webpack config file: http://pastebin.com/tf5Ag90x

Comment: Check this post: [Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725181/not-compatible-with-your-operating-system-or-architecture-fsevents1-0-11) I hope this post can help you.

Comment: Take a look at this post. [Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725181/not-compatible-with-your-operating-system-or-architecture-fsevents1-0-11)

Comment: Take a look at this post. [Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725181/not-compatible-with-your-operating-system-or-architecture-fsevents1-0-11)

Answer (score 5):

I'll include this here because it fixed my issue. It may or may not fix yours, depending on if your paths in your post are actually the paths you're using. If it doesn't resolve your issue, at least it'll solve somebodies cause this question comes up first thing for this issue.

You can't have a path with "(" or ")" in it, because the is-glob dependency thinks it's a glob if you do. If you must put your project in a path with "(" (like Program Files (x86)), then you must add something like this to your is-glob module in node_modules:

```
  if (typeof str === 'string' && str.indexOf('Program Files (x86)') > -1)
     return false
```

Comment: Other special characters might be a problem too. Exclamation mark was also a problem in my case. I simply had to create a different directory with `[a-z_]` characters only and work in that one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch).  I find myself in the same mess.  Windows/Linux cannot support `fsevents` considering its strictly for OSX.  Support for Linux, for example, is through [inotify](http://c4milo.github.io/node-inotify/).

It seems `fswatch` provides a cross-platform filesystem monitor, so you should be all set if you use with your windows machine.